# Spatial Join with no Related Primary Key

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, spatialite, query

The example I am showing is a VERY simplified version of my dataset which actually represents 100's of points.  I have point A representing a building (centroid of the building polygon), but no other relative attribute info.  Point B contains the address attribute information for that building.

[image]

Looking at the simplified table info, there isn't anything relatable between the two layers, other than they are fairly close to each other.  Is there a spatial query I can create that would join these two tables, maybe somehow based on the X coordinates being with a few hundreds in distance from each other or maybe create a buffer in GIS?  I don't really know much about creating SQL queries, so honestly I really don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: You stated that the points were in the polygons. Surely that would qualify as a Within relationship. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Need more information, does every point have a relation? If so you could join by nearest

Answer (score 0):

With a few hints from the comments, here is what I did to solve the task:
[image]

Starting with the two original layers: (1) Buildings = polygons, which have no other project related data, but do have osm_id. (2) Addresses, which hold relivant project data, but are in point format
[image]

From the Processing Tools, I used Join attributes by nearest and used the 2 layers above for the 2 required inputs.  This created a new layer named 'Joined layer'

This gave me all the attribute data, but in point form on the map, so I did a join for the Building (polygon) layer to the newly created 'Joined layer', using the osm_id attribute for each layer as a primary key
[image]

Which resulted in the original Buildings, shown as polygons, now having address information associated with them

[image]
[image]